# Can I integrate Spring with wamp server for MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I am new for spring and I have already installed MySQL using wamp, I was following some tutorials http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-JdbcTemplate-tutorial is one of java's framework tutorial. 
In Tutorial, all I have done same except using MySQL.

Every time, I am getting this error

```
Oct 10, 2016 1:09:11 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@729f624a: startup date [Mon Oct 10 01:09:11 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 10, 2016 1:09:11 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/PropertyAccessor
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:481)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.springDBDemo.Test.main(Test.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 5 more
```

So I don't know what is the issue.

Dropbox which has my demo project.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mmz87o9vstgw5a/springDBDemo.zip?dl=0

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this jar if you using add it like:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If not try to add to the folder of class path

Comment: Thanks , I have found solution. Just added more jar files like web, test and more.